# Which HTTP method to use to build a REST API to perform following operation?

Tags: rest, architecture

I am looking for a REST API to do following

1. Search based on parameters sent, if results found, return the results.
2. If no results found, create a record based on search parameters sent.

Can this be accomplished by creating one single API or 2 separate APIs are required?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect this to be handled by a single request to a single resource.

> Which HTTP method to use

This depends on the semantics of what is going on - we care about what the messages mean, rather than how the message handlers are implemented.

The key idea is the [uniform interface](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5) constraint it REST; because we have a common understanding of what HTTP methods mean, general purpose connectors in the HTTP application can do useful work (for example, returning cached responses to a request without forwarding them to the origin server).

Thus, when trying to choose which HTTP method is appropriate, we can consider the implications the choice has on general purpose components (like web caches, browsers, crawlers, and so on).

GET announces that the meaning of the request is effectively read only; because of this, general purpose components know that they can dispatch this request at any time (for instance, a user agent might dispatch a GET request before the user decides to follow the link, to make the experience faster).

That's fine when you intend the request to provide the client with a copy of your search results, and the fact that you might end up making changes to server local state is just an implementation detail.

On the other hand, if the client is trying to edit the results of a particular search (but sometimes the server doesn't need to change anything), then GET isn't appropriate, and you should [use POST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post).

A way to think about the difference is to consider what action you want to be taken when an intermediate cache holds a response from an earlier copy of "the same" request.  If you want the cache to reuse the response, GET is the best; on the other hand, if you want the cache to throw away the old response (and possibly store the new one), then you should be using POST.